# Drupal private field

Tags: users

I have got  a status column for a web form event and so that it is editable by admin. Once the status is updated the end user is not able to see it, because it is a private field.

Comment: I have used the field permissions module and made it private field

Answer (score 1):

Use one theses modules :

[User Field Privacy](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_field_privacy)

> - All the user fields should have an "alterable privacy" checkbox.
> - If this checkbox is ticked, the user should be presented with an    additional checkbox for the privacy-enabled fields on user edit forms 
>     to be able to make that fields' values private.
> - If this second checkbox is ticked for a field of a user, only the    site administrators (members of roles with the "Access private
>     fields" permission) and the user herself should be able to view that
>     field's value.

[CCK Private Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/cck_private_fields)

> This module allows users to mark administrator selected CCK fields as
>   Public (visible to everyone), Hidden (visible to node author, hidden
>   from everyone else) or Private (visible to node author and "friends";
>   see requirements section below).

[Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions)

> - Enable field permissions on any entity, not just nodes.
> - Role-based field permissions allowing different viewing patterned    based on what access the user has.
> - Author-level permissions allow viewing and editing of fields based on    who the entity owner is.
> - Permissions for each field are not enabled by default. Instead,    administrators can enable these permissions explicitly for the fields 
>     where this feature is needed.

Comment: I am using Private Field on a web form and once the status, and this field is not visible by the sumitter (intended and working fine). Once the field is submitted and admin changes the field, this field should be viewed by the submitter.